# Let reviewers know when reopen queue entries have been edited multiple times since closure

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, reopen-closed

[This reopen queue entry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4096933) prompted this request.

When you view the revision tab, you see what is effectively a no-op edit.  This is because the question was edited two times post-closure, the first editing in some code, the second removing it.  The removal was more correct, as the addition improperly was an "answer."

Condensing these multiple edits is a great idea, but it would be valuable to know that the question was edited multiple times when viewing the diff.  I had to click into the revision history to figure out what, if anything, was missing.

Answer (score 4):

This is really far more complexity than is needed for such a simple tool. If you're interested in knowing what changed (and I don't blame you for being such a voyeur - *edits are sexy!*) then **just click through to the revision history!**

[image: the revision history link]

But generally-speaking, when reviewing questions in the reopen queue you should **evaluate them on their merits as they appear** - *not* on what has changed. Don't re-open questions just because the asker has made some effort - if it didn't suffice to make the question suitable, it was *wasted* effort. Likewise, don't fail to reopen questions that were closed incorrectly just because the edit was minor - they still don't need to be closed. You're not reviewing the edit, after all: you're reviewing the *question!*

Comment: TBH this is more of a UI thing.  While the link to the revision history is available, it isn't there on the tab showing the condensed revision history.  As an active participant on Meta, I know what conditions cause closed questions to enter the reopen queue, and that editing is one of them.  In this case, a confusing edit entered the queue, and It Would Be Nice(tm) to have some indication why the revision history was why it was without clicking back to another tab.

Answer (score 3):

Let me create a better suggestion: if the diff between the closed version of the post and the most recent version of the post has absolutely no change to the content, then toss it out of the queue, and invalidate any existing reviews on it.

The only reason you want to be told there were two edits is because there doesn't appear to have been any change. Items are tossed in to the review queue if they are edited after being closed to give askers a chance to improve their post for re-evaluation. If they didn't actually make any revision, tossing them in to the queue for that reason seems rather pointless.

So if the diff between the version when closed and the version after editing are the same, toss it out of the queue if the reason for the review is 'post has been edited'. Test to see if this is the case prior to showing the review task, and if the posts are the same invalidate any existing review votes on the question and take it out of the queue. If it was tossed in to the queue manually by someone clicking reopen, leave it in the queue. This makes me wonder if people are abusing this to manually try to get their own posts reopened (editing and editing back changes to get it in the review queue).