# Please make pending edit suggesters be @reply-able in comments

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits, comment-replies

When reviewing suggested edits, it often happens that I'd like to say something to the edit suggester, but I can't. The ability to reply to them would be a way to solve edit problems much more amicably, rather than rejecting possibly approvable edits without giving them a reason.

Commenting on unrelated posts is clearly not okay. Rejecting the edit with a custom "causes harm" reasoning is also not a good solution, because:

1. This doesn't notify the edit suggester; they would need to dig out the review for that, which rarely happens.
2. It can only happen when rejecting the suggestion, which is often not my intent.

Besides that:

- past approved and binding editors of posts are already reply-able<sup>1</sup>,
- there is already an ongoing [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to) to allow replying to *rejected* editors in comments
- it's possible for users with pending edit suggestions to edit their edit proposals, so that those edits are also incorporated into the same review (i.e. an unlimited grace period while the edit is still pending)
- the "Improve Edit" option may not be the right option, as the reviewer may not be entirely aware of what the edit proposer is on to in some cases, or they may need further clarification of the edit before making a decision

**I am asking to allow @reply-ing to users who have a pending suggested edit on the post.**

Note, this *does not mean* the overloading of their inbox - they won't be notified of all comments, only ones that @-mention their name. Only the post owner would get a notification from all the comments on their post, as normal.

Another use case of this feature would be in case someone who has accidentally created a second account or has lost access to their original account suggests an edit to one of their own posts; since the user won't (be able to) see notifications on the first account, one can mention to their second account with the fact that they have another account and instructions to have their account merged.

<sup>1</sup><sub>As @Glorfindel mentions, they are already pingable. But pending and rejected suggested editors are still not.</sub>

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Oops :-( What if the edit happens while the reopen review is going on, does it count? As 10k, you can see more in the review stats.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Maybe I could ask yet another feature, that also the first edit following the "leave closed" decision should start a new reopen review entity, not only the first edit after the closure :-) And I could refer this post as an example. :-)

Comment: It's by design that questions can only be added to the queue once per closure by editing. That said, it may be worth examining creating reopen vote tasks if the question is voted for reopening after the review is complete, regardless of whether the prior votes have aged out or not. You may encounter some headwind though, since a lot of users believe that it should be more difficult to reopen questions than close them. See also [this related discussion I started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315246/how-can-we-prevent-misinformed-reopen-reviews-as-a-result-of-edits-during-the-re)

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Nice idea :-) Pingability would be surely useful...

Comment: [Yet another example](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16753). I had to reject the edit suggestion, and I have no way to ping him. Even if he had at least a post, anywhere, I should ping him in some offtopic way. It is clearly bad.

Comment: A quick note: this can't possibly work for *anonymous* suggested editors, as those come from *no* account rather than an unregistered account. (The edit you linked in your comment above appears to have come "from an anonymous user", but it could have been from a registered user who later deleted their account.)